# Beginning Java: 'for' loops

Tags: java

I want a program that prints the following:
(3,0), (2,1) , (1,2) and (0,3)

But I can't get it right, see the code below. What would be the appropriate syntax to get what I want?

```
public class experiment1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 3, int j = 0; i >= 0, j <= 3; i--, j++)
        {
            System.out.println(i + "\t"+ j);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need nested loops.

Comment: Why do you use two vars? It looks like `j = i - 3` for `0 <= i <= 3`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to include two variables in that loop. In general, try to avoid over-complicating code by adding extra variables / unnecessary machinery.

Try this out:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
   System.out.println((3-i) + "\t" + i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- Use an && rather than a comma: (i >= 0) && (j <= 3)
- Use a single variable, and perform arithmetic on it in the body of the loop: System.out.println( i + "," + (3-i))

The comma operator takes two expressions, performs both of them, and returns the value of the last.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct, except for the syntax error. Without changing much your code, the "for" would look like this after the fix:

```
for (int i = 3, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) 
{
     System.out.println(i + "\t"+ j);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The best thing I could come up for this is using modulo.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    System.out.println("(" + i % 3 + "," + i + "));
}
```

This eliminates the need for a second variable.